# Output each element of list of list from Python to .csv file

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv, xlsxwriter

I am trying to write each **list-element** from a list of list in Python to a .csv file, but I keep getting the strings whose letters are space-separated for some unknown reasons. A sample code is below:

```
import xlsxwriter

S = [[1, 7, 8, 0], [4, 5, 7, 3], [2, 9, 10, 11, 6]]

with open('S_N=6.csv', 'wt') as graph:

    graphWriter = csv.writer(graph, delimiter = ' ')

    for x in range(len(S)):

      graphWriter.writerow('set S' + str(x+1)  + ':=')
```

**My intended output** (notice that the **index** i in S[i] can be computed as (the last element in each list/3) + 1)

```
set S[1] = 1 7 8
set S[2] = 4 5 7
set S[3] = 2 9 10 11
```

Can someone please help me with this problem? Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output file is not CSV. It's makes no sense to use a CSV writer to generate it. It's just a bunch of lines, so write just a bunch of lines.

```
S = [[1, 7, 8, 0], [4, 5, 7, 3], [2, 9, 10, 11, 6]]

with open('S_N=6.csv', 'w') as fp:
    for x in S:
        *items, idx = x
        idx = int(idx / 3 + 1)
        items = ' '.join(map(str, items))
        fp.write(f'set S[{idx}] = {items}\n')
```

- `*items, idx = x` assigns all but the last list element in `x` to `items`, and the last element to `idx`.
- `idx / 3 + 1` returns a `float`, i.e. `1.0` and so on. It must be converted to `int` explicitly.
- `f'...'` is a format string, you can use Python expressions in curly braces inside.

This writes:

```
set S[1] = 1 7 8
set S[2] = 4 5 7
set S[3] = 2 9 10 11
```

Since format strings can contain complex expressions, you could write it as follows, if you really wanted to:

```
for x in S:
    *items, idx = x
    fp.write(f'set S[{int(idx / 3 + 1)}] = {' '.join(map(str, items))}\n')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help! Your code works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
S = [[1, 7, 8, 0], [4, 5, 7, 3], [2, 9, 10, 11, 6]]
with open('S_N=6.csv', 'w+') as f:
    for x in S:
        f.write('set S[' + str((int(x[-1]/3))+1) + '] = ' + ' '.join(str(a) for a in x[:-1]) + '\n')
```

It will write into the file `S_N=6.csv` the following output:

```
set S[1] = 1 7 8
set S[2] = 4 5 7
set S[3] = 2 9 10 11
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works like a charm!